# Получение значение при выборе элемента

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть выпадающий список:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>Один</li>
                    <li>Два</li>
                    <li>Три</li>
</ul>
```

Как с помощью jquery получить значение (например data-...), при выборе какого-либо `li` (т.е. при действии `change`)?

Comment: а что такое "data-" это атрибут ? или вы хотите получить текст из <li> ?

Comment: Да атрибут, желательно и текст и и дата атрибут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое, при `Click` получаете данные:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click',function(){
var attr = $(this).attr('data-info');
var text = $(this).text();

console.log(attr+'  '+text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li data-info="1">Один</li>
                    <li data-info="2">Два</li>
                    <li data-info="3">Три</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: почему не `$(this).data('info');` / `$(this).data().info`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в принципе согласен, более короткий синтакс, я просто привел один из возможностей )